# PHP redirection in an autorefresh div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm stuck with php redirection after session_destroy. I make an auto refresh in some element. I write my code like this :

**navigation.php (after login success) :**

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $token = $_SESSION['token'];
?>
<html>
<head>
   <title>....</title>
   ...... CSS/JS.......
</head>
<div class="menu">
    ..... MY WEB MENU ......
</div>
```

**index.php :**

```
<?php
   include "navigation.php";
   include "function.php";
?>
<body>
  <div class="container">
     <div class="load_data">
         <?php
            include "load_data.php";
         ?>
     </div>
  </div>
</body>
<?php
  include "footer.php";
?>
```

**footer.php :**

```
</html>
<script>
   $(function() {
       setInterval(function(){
          $('.load_data').load('load_data.php');
       },5000);
   });
</script>
```

**function.php:**

```
<?php
   function A($token){
      global $data_counter;

       .... CALL API BY cURL BASED ON TOKEN .......

       if($result == "200"){
            $data_counter = count($decode['data']);
       }else{
          if (session_destroy()) { 
            header("location:../");
            exit();
         }
      }
   }
?>
```

**load_data.php :**

```
<?php
  include_once("function.php");
  A($token)

  ..... DO SOME OPERATION AFTER GET RESULT FROM FUNCTION A ......      
?>
```

So, I think my problem is in **function.php**. If when the API return instead of "200" it will destroy all session and redirect to login page, but it become failed because my login page show in the container body like this :[image]

Does anyone know what should I change?

Comment: According to the error messages, your webserver does not have permission to write into the C:\xampp\tmp folder to create/manage the session.

Answer (score 0):

I've figure it out. It can be solved by using javascript `window.location` then clear the session by `session_destroy();`